# Delay when trying to play animation again

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a simple task, on click to play the animation, first forward, then backward. I had such a situation that when the clicks are continuous, everything works as it should, but it is worth making a pause between the next click and there is a delay during playback, which feels like exactly the same time while I was waiting. I thought it might be worth resetting Animator-> enabled = false, but then the animation loses its current state and you have to return to the beginning. Here's a piece of code:

```
     if(_currentState == State.Forward)
     {
         _animator.SetFloat ("Direction", 1);
         _animator.Play(clip.name, 0);
     }
     else
     {
         _animator.SetFloat ("Direction", -1);
         _animator.Play(clip.name, 0);
     }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

#### If you used arrows to connect the animations for each other:

1. Select the arrows which connect the animations for each other
2. Turn (Has exit time) off